# Associated enum Type Implement CaseItratable

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have two enums and one associated enum. I need to get all the possible cases from enum A and enum B at once.

```
enum A {
    case a
    case b
    case c
}

enum B {
    case d
    case e
    case f
}

enum C {
    case first(A)
    case second(B)
}

extension C: CaseItratable {
 //How to implement?
}
```

Need a allCases method in enum C which returns all cases in enum A and all cases in enum B

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You want to simply get all A and B cases in a method in enum C?

Comment: yes I wan to get all possible cases in enum C

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Conform `enum A` and `enum B` to `CaseIterable` protocol

```
enum A: CaseIterable {
    case a, b, c
}

enum B: CaseIterable {
    case d, e, f
}
```

**2.** Get all cases of `enum A` and `enum B` using **`allCases`**.

```
enum C {
    case first(A)
    case second(B)

    var casesOfA: [A] {
        return A.allCases //here...
    }

    var casesOfB: [B] {
        return B.allCases //here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more helpful if `A` and `B` are `CaseIterable` as well, then you can implement `CaseIterable` in `C` like this:

```
extension A: CaseIterable {}
extension B: CaseIterable {}

extension C: CaseIterable {

    static var allCases: [C] {
        return A.allCases.map(C.first) + B.allCases.map(C.second)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the type alias, that is inferred automatically.

Comment: @Saranjith Which version of Swift are you using? It works fine on Swift 5.1.

Comment: @Saranjith What did you do?